# How to fix Steering wheel play - DIY

Tags: nissan, steering-wheel, sentra

I drive a 2015 Nissan Sentra.

my steering has this issue as show in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FXdyhT39q2Y
at time 1:20

can we fix this by ourself?. It would be glad if you can share any DIY video for fixing this on **Nissan Sentra 2015**.

The problem is most of the videos are either for different cars or they are tiny hacks.

If this is do able at home, I would like to fix this properly.

Comment: If a knowledgeable Nissan Sentra person doesn't comment, perhaps searching for Nissan Sentra forums may help. Members are owners sharing free info and experiences. Attempting to use YouTube videos not specifically related to year, make and model, can be misleading and counter productive, especially if you're not familiar with steering systems.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Your Sentra will have a rack & pinion style steering arrangement. There is no adjustment for your car like what's in the video you shared. With it only being a 2015 model, I'd be highly surprised if there is even an issue with there being too much steering wheel play. More than likely the issue will be in the other parts of the steering, such as the inner/outer tie rods, but again, I'm thinking this is doubtful. Maybe you can share a video of your car and the exact problem you are seeing?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Sure I can do that. I will create a video and share it with you.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I checked for play. There is no play. Its just Electronic Steering wheel is so loose, even slight movement is causing my wheel to move. So, I felt there was a play happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to identify where the play starts.  Get someone to sit rocking the steering wheel back and forth while you check for movement in all of the steering components as in [this diagram](https://i0.wp.com/gomechanic.in/blog/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/racknpinion.jpg?resize=413%2C373&is-pending-load=1#038;ssl=1) -

[image]

Start by looking in the engine compartment where the steering column comes through the bulkhead/firewall, is the end of the steering column moving?

There will be universal joints on the intermediate shaft, is one side of the universal joint able to move relative to the other side?

Where the intermediate shaft goes into the steering rack, is the input moving?

On left wheel and right wheel side of the steering rack, are the rack ends moving?

Where the tie/track rods connect by ball joints to the wheel hubs are the ball joints moving?

Doing this will identify which component is worn and needs replacing.